# Is there any way to break the Bash `quote` function?

Tags: bash, shell, escaping

Bash in Ubuntu (13.04) seems to have this `quote` function by default:

```
quote () 
{ 
    local quoted=${1//\'/\'\\\'\'};
    printf "'%s'" "$quoted"
}
```

This function should always return a correct shell escaped version of it's first parameter.

Is there any input string which will break this function (i.e. return a string unusable for shell input)?

---

Examples:

`quote "A string's but a string."`

```
'A string'\''s but a string.'
```

`quote "A newline *doesn't*`
`seem to break anything..."`

```
'A newline *doesn'\''t*
seem to break anything...'
```

---

Comment: Given that it seems to assume you can include an escaped single quote inside a single-quoted string, I'd say there are very many strings that are unusable for shell input.

Comment: The function appears to be from `/etc/bash_completion` on my Ubuntu 12.04.  Look around line 187

Comment: I'm looking at the output of `quote \'`, and I'm not sure what the output is supposed to represent.

Comment: @chepner The trick is to try `eval echo "$(quote \')"`. If that works, it's fine.

Comment: I'm getting an unexpected EOF error.

Comment: Yes, that makes more sense.

Comment: Alternatively, `quote() { printf "%q" "$1"; }`

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be "bullet-proof".

A singly-quoted item in the shell is absolutely anything between single quotes, other than a single quote. The single quote can be pseudo-included by using the sequence `'\''` which terminates one quoting, then backslash-quotes the quote, and then re-starts a new quoting.

This substitution is all that the function does.

The output of the function is single-quote syntax which represents the input string.

The function even defeats the "process-substitution-swallows-trailing-newlines" issue.

Ordinarily, if you have some function or command which outputs multiple lines, followed by one or more blank lines, and then capture it with process substitution like this:

```
FOO=$(command)
```

the trailing blank lines are gone.  Since `quote`'s output is wrapped in single quotes, trailing newlines in the string are protected, allowing this to work:

```
FOO=$("a
b
c


")

echo "$FOO"
'a
b
c


'
```

Clearly, the output of `quote` is meant to be `eval`-ed, and `quote` ensures that the result of this `eval` is the original argument to `quote` without any accidental expansion, splitting or stripping of whitespace.